# Translating MYSQL to MSSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am new to MYSQL and I am trying to translate this into MSSQL.

I don't understand the highlighted parts......

Q1. How does the date join works...?
...join (select @last_time:=current_timestamp,@last_object:=null)?

Q2. How to translate "@last_time:=state_time,@last_object:=object_id" in MSSQL?

Thanks for helping guys!

---

```
SELECT c.*,
    coalesce(b.type, 'history') AS type,
    coalesce(b.STATE, current_state) AS STATE,
    coalesce(b.state_type, 1) AS state_type,
    coalesce(CASE 
            WHEN b.start_time < range_start
                THEN range_start
            ELSE b.start_time
            END, range_start) AS start_time,
    coalesce(CASE 
            WHEN b.end_time > range_end
                THEN range_end
            ELSE b.end_time
            END, range_end) AS end_time,
    coalesce(b.time_span, timestampdiff(SECOND, range_start, range_end)) AS time_span,
    range_start,
    range_end,
    timestampdiff(SECOND, range_start, range_end) AS total_span,
    comment_data
FROM (
    SELECT d.object_id,
        d.name1,
        d.name2,
        d.name1 AS display_name,
        'top' AS LEVEL,
        CASE 
            WHEN d.name1 = 'Server Hosting'
                THEN 'medium'
            ELSE 'high'
            END AS `tab`  ,
        e.current_state,
        d.name1 AS setorder
    FROM N_objects a
    JOIN N_servicegroups b ON a.object_id = b.servicegroup_object_id
    JOIN N_servicegroup_members c ON b.servicegroup_id = c.servicegroup_id
    JOIN N_objects d ON c.service_object_id = d.object_id  left
    JOIN N_servicestatus e ON e.service_object_id = c.service_object_id
    WHERE a.name1 = 'Dashboard'
        AND d.is_active = 1
        AND d.object_id IN (895)
    ) c   * *
JOIN (
    SELECT last_day(current_timestamp) + interval 1 day - interval 1 month AS range_start,
        last_day(current_timestamp) + interval 1 day AS range_end
    ) d * *
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT b.*
    FROM (
        SELECT type,
            object_id,
            STATE,
            state_type,
            start_time,
            end_time,
            timestampdiff(SECOND, start_time, end_time) AS time_span,
            '' AS comment_data
        FROM (
              * * SELECT 'history' AS type,
                object_id,
                STATE,
                state_type,
                CASE 
                    WHEN @last_object != object_id
                        THEN current_timestamp
                    ELSE @last_time
                    END AS end_time,
                state_time AS start_time,
                @last_time: = state_time,
                @last_object: = object_id
            FROM N_statehistory a
            JOIN (
                SELECT @last_time: = current_timestamp,
                    @last_object: = NULL
                ) b * *
            ORDER BY object_id,
                start_time DESC
            ) a

        UNION ALL

        SELECT 'downtime' AS type,
            object_id,
            0,
            1,
            scheduled_start_time,
            scheduled_end_time,
            timestampdiff(SECOND, scheduled_start_time, scheduled_end_time),
            comment_data
        FROM N_downtimehistory
        ) b
    JOIN (
        SELECT last_day(current_timestamp) + interval 1 day - interval 1 month AS range_start,
            last_day(current_timestamp) + interval 1 day AS range_end
        ) d ON b.start_time BETWEEN range_start
            AND range_end
        OR b.end_time BETWEEN range_start
            AND range_end
    ) b ON b.object_id = c.object_id
ORDER BY setorder,
    start_time
```

Comment: @JNevill Thanks for the editing. I was trying to reformat that but It wasn't that friendly look.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this by copying the query into SQL Server Management Studio, run it (which would of course throw errors), and start tackling the errors one by one. I'd probably try and lift out smaller chunks of the whole thing and get them working individually if I could.

Your `:=` operator (`@last_time:=state_time,@last_object:=object_id`) I think is an assignment operator; it is assigning the `@` variables to those corresponding field values.  In MSSQL you would do a `SET @last_time = state_time` or `SELECT @last_time=state_time`

I *think* from your example and some documentation (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) it looks like it might be trying to do some sort of iterative maintenance, like for each row returned it is updating the `@last_time` and `@last_object` variables for the next round.  It's been awhile since I worked with MySQL so I'm not sure if that's an expected behavior or not.

It might be easier in porting if you tackle the problem the query is trying to solve and build the query from there rather than trying to directly port one's syntax to the other.